# sed to remove first of consecutive lines that begin with a pattern

Tags: sed

I have an HTML file where some lines begin with `<br>`. If there are two in a row, I want to delete the first. It seems like this should work...

```
sed '/^<br>/{N;/^<br>/ s/^.*\n//}'
```

...but it doesn't.

**Edit:**

Input:

```
<br>Here's a line I don't want.
<br>Here's a line I do want.
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Output:

```
<br>Here's a line I do want.
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

**Edit 2:**

I've narrowed the problem to the command working half the time. If line 1 and line 2 start with `<br>`, line 1 is properly deleted, but the script moves on to lines 3 and 4, without first checking 2 and 3.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: If you're looking for two `<br>`'s in a row, why not use `sed "s/^<br><br>/<br>/g" test.html`?

Comment: Edited for input/output.

Comment: Your sed seems correct. What output do you have?

Comment: It appears that your sed command is missing a semicolon. Is that output what you *want,* or what you're *getting?*

Comment: Kenavoz, it works for the sample given, but not with longer series of lines that begin with `<br>`. Beta, well, same response. See edit 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/^<br>/N;{/\n<br>/D;}' file
```

When `^<br>` is found, `N` adds next line to the pattern space. If this next line begins with `<br>`, `D` deletes the first portion of the pattern space (ie first line starting with `br`).